# Image convolution, motion blur

Tags: image-processing, convolution

I define my degradation function as
$$H(x,y;a,b,t)=\frac{T}{z}\sin z~e^{-jz}$$
where
$$z=\pi(ax+by)$$
So I write

```
H[a_, b_, T_] := 
  Function[{x, y}, z = Pi*(a*x + b*y); If[z == 0, T, T*N[Sin[z]*Exp[-I*z]/z]]];
```

But when I convolve it with image

```
Image[Abs[InverseFourier[Fourier[img]*Array[H[a, b, T], {row, col}]]], "Real"]
```

The blurred image is almost white. What's wrong with my program?

#### Edit

Here is my runnable program

```
img = Import["Lena.tif", "Data"];
{row, col} = Dimensions[img];
H[a_, b_, T_] := Function[{x, y}, z = Pi*(a*x+b*y); T*N[Sinc[z]*Exp[-I*z]]];
filter = Array[H[0.1, 0.1, 1], {row, col}];
Image[Abs[InverseFourier[Fourier[img]*filter]], "Real"]
```

Comment: Why don't you use ImageConvolve? It's built for convolving images.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I use standard "Lena"

Comment: @bills I wanna implement the function on my own before I use it. That helps me understand better.

Comment: @bills And I tried, but it says I can't convolve with a complex matrix.

Comment: Well then you are doing it the hard way. You are multiplying a sinc in the frequency domain by the FFT of the image. This is the same as convolving with a rectangle in the spatial domain. Why not do actual convolution? If you want motion blur, the first example in the ImageConvolve is the way to go.

Comment: You cannot act directly `Fourier[img]`, use `Fourier[ImageData@img]`

Comment: @bills I just pick this degradation function from an example in the textbook. If I change that, I have to use the same method.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Yes, my `img=Import["image","Data"];`. No error appears in my program.

Comment: Could you please make your code self-sufficient, run-able - so we won't spend time guessing what it is, but rather invest it in helping you? Image data, variables row, col, etc.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I edit my question. Could you help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to go line by line to see your errors. You have to do this for each RGB channel separately.

```
img = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
data = ImageData /@ ColorSeparate[img];
{row, col} = Dimensions[data[[1]]];

H[a_, b_, T_] := Function[{x, y}, z = Pi*(a*x + b*y); T*N[Sinc[z]*Exp[-I*z]]]

filter = Array[H[0.1, 0.1, 1], {row, col}];
filter // Abs // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

```
ColorCombine[Image[Abs[InverseFourier[Fourier[#]*filter]], "Real"] & /@ data]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, Thank you. I will check. Sorry to say that. My "Lena" is gray.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't see the difference except the color part. But when I run it on a gray-level "Lena", I always obtain white.

Comment: @zhangwfjh Just replace top line with `img = ColorConvert[Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"], "Grayscale"];` and it will work.

Comment: If I understand right of your comment, you mean the method doesn't work for my "Lena" because it has only one channel? My "lena" data has only two dimensions with size 256*256.

Comment: I do not have *your* Lena, they way you import it fails for me. This is why I gave you a line which makes a gray Lena. Just make replace 1st line with it and code now will work with gray image. `img = ColorConvert[Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"], "Grayscale"]`

Comment: Thank you very much. I find it different between `Import["image","Data"]` and `ImageData[Import["image"],"Real"]`